# Prove AB is hermitian if A is hermitian and B is hermitian

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ and $B$ are two hermitian transformations, prove that $AB$ is hermitian if $AB = BA$, knowing that a hermitian transformation is one such that $(T(f), g) = (f, T(g))$ and basic axioms for inner products: $(x,y) = (y,x)$, $(x,x) > 0$, $(cx, y) = c(x,y)$, and $(x,y+z) = (x,y) + (x,z)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\langle ABf, g \rangle = \langle Bf, Ag \rangle = \langle f, BAg \rangle = \langle f, ABg \rangle.$$

Here

- I "=" $\longleftarrow$ $A$ is Hermitian,
- II "=" $\longleftarrow$ $B$ is Hermitian,
- III "=" $\longleftarrow$ $AB = BA$.

Comment: How do you get from $(ABf,g)=(Bf,Ag)=(f,BAg)$? A and B are transformations and not scalars so can you provide a justification for that?

Comment: @bob, I added more explanation to the answer.

Comment: Heh, I actually saw it just after I posted that question; thanks for trying to clarify, though.

Answer (score 3):

We prove that $(AB)^*=AB$ by these equalities
$$\langle x,(AB)^*y\rangle=\langle ABx,y\rangle=\langle Bx,A^*y\rangle=\langle Bx,Ay\rangle=\langle x,B^*Ay\rangle=\langle x,BAy\rangle=\langle x,ABy\rangle$$